# concurrent.futures.Executor.map: calculate function inputs lazily

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some code similar to the following:

```
def worker(l:list):
   ...
really_big_list = [......]
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future = {executor.submit(worker, l[i:i+100]) for i in range(0, len(really_big_list), 10))
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        data = future.result()
```

Note that the workers take slices of size 100 but it only goes up by 10 at a time. In this code, even though I am only using 5 workers, to calculate the inputs to each worker I'll need to use 10 times the size of `really_big_list`. This is simply too much memory for what I am doing. Is there a way to defer calculating `l[i:100]` until that worker is started?

Comment: *I'll need to use 10 times the size of really_big_list* - it's not 10 times of size of your input list but `really_big_list // 10`. And `l[i:100]` is incorrect slicing, say for an input list of size `1e6` the slice `l[110:100]` (and further) will give an empty list. Put corrections in your current code.

Comment: Oops, that should be l[i:i+100]. I'll edit it to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest an alternative - use `multiprocessing.Pool` and function [`.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) or [`.imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered), e.g.:

```py
from itertools import islice
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep


def worker(l: list):
    sleep(1)
    return sum(l)


# from https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html
def batched(iterable, n):
    "Batch data into tuples of length n. The last batch may be shorter."
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("n must be at least one")
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch


if __name__ == "__main__":
    really_big_list = list(range(10_000))
    with Pool(5) as pool:
        # use `.imap` or `.imap_unordered` here
        for result in pool.imap(worker, batched(really_big_list, 10)):
            print(result)
```